# HTML and CSS code so picture next to each other instead it should be shown the picture when user click next arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css

So when i have html and css code below where html index.html suppose to have sildeshow the Web browser does each picture display next to each other vertically when I hit next arrow it Becomes a slideshow and it does not show the picture next to each other anymore.

```css
html {    
    background: url('./images/cover2.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;     
    background-size: cover;
    
}

body{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 125vh;
    padding: 1px;
}

.ImgNavagation{
    height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.92;
    max-width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

h1{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: black;
    max-width: 100%;
    
}

.navigation {
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    list-style: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    
}
.location-cont1{
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
   
}
.location-cont2{
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
   
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.ImgNavagation *{
    display:inline;
    margin: 5px;
}
.slideshow-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}

.myslides{
   
    display: none;
}


.prev, .next{
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0,0.34);
}

.dot{
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;

}
.active, .dot:hover{
    background-color: #717171;

}

.fade{
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.0s;
    
}

@keyframes fade{
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
}

.mission_content{
    margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    border: 1.5px solid white;
    max-width: 895px;
    
    
}

#About{
    margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    border: 1.5px solid white;
    max-width: 895px;
    
}

#Contact{
    background-color: #282424;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;

    
}

#Contact a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#Contact a:hover{
    background-color: #E91E63;
    border-radius : 20%;
    color: white;
    
    
}

#ontact a:active{
    background-color: #E91E63;
    border-radius : 20%;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!--<body>-->
<div class = "ImgNavagation">
    <img src="./images/bookicon.png" width="80" height="40" >


    <h1>Singh Books & Co.</h1>

    <ul class="navigation">

        <li class=" navigation nav-success"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li class=" navigation nav-success"><a href="#location">Location</a></li>
        <li class=" navigation nav-success"><a href="#Contact">ContactUS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="./images/insidelook1.jpg" style="width: 100%">


    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="./images/insidelook2.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="./images/insidelook3.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>


<div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>


    <h2>Mission</h2>
    <div class = "mission_content">
    <p>Our mission is Singh book is provide every book, meet customer demand and supply and 
        serve a best customer service. Also we buy book from buyer they want to sell. 
    </p>

</div>




    <h2>About Us</h2>
    <div id="About">
    <p>Singh Book & Co. is owned by Harry Singh since 1990. 
        Singh Book & Co have multiple location around Ohio, Michgan and ship nationwide USA.
        Stores are Open until 8am - 6pm and 24/7 for nationwide order.
        Singh Book & Co. Carry every genere type of books Fiction, Non-fiction, Memiors...etc.
        Also have different format of book hardcover or paperback.
    </p>

</div>
<div id="location">

    <h2>Location:</h2>
    <div class="location-cont1">
    <h4>Ohio:</h4>

    <ul>
        <li>Toledo</li>
        <li>Cleveland</li>
        <li>Dayton</li>
        <li>Cinncanti</li>
        <li>Colmubus</li>
        <li>Sandusky</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="location-cont2">
    <h4>Michgan:</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>Grand Rapid</li>
        <li>Detroit</li>
        <li>Farmightion Hill</li>
        <li>Novi</li>
        <li>Travese City</li>

    </ul>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="Contact">
    <h3>Support Service:</h3>
    <a>Email Address: SinghbookCo@gmail.com</a>
    <a>Phone Number: 3214892034</a>
</div>
       
       
<!--    </body>
</html>-->
```

```js
let slideIndex =1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n){
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n){
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
    if(n > slides.length){
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if(n < 1){
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    for(i=0; i< slides.length; i++){
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for(i=0; i<dots.length; i++ ){
        dots[i].className=dots[i].className.replace("active","");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display  = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";

}
```

I tired playing the slideshow-container css class tag but it none of the properties will fix this bug on website. Not sure what to do any help would be appreciated. I'm starting my journey in html and css as beginner but wanted to get somebody else opinion what I am not thinking to try.

Comment: FYI: I converted your code into a snippet so it can be run inside your question.  It looks like your code calls some JavaScript which is not included. Please edit your code and add the javascript so the snippet functions to reproduce the issue you are having.  When you edit your question, at the bottom you can press the "edit the above snippet" link and add the JS in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before and with just a quick glance you are calling event that you do not have a definition for.
In these lines :

```
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

&

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
```

the 'onClick' properties are set to a JavaScript function, one is currentSlide(x) and the other is plusSlides(y), with x and y being arguments that are passed in them.

The 'onClick' property is an event that basically does whatever you write in it whenever you click the corresponding element, and it is very common to use JavaScript function that can do things to your HTML interactively when you click something. In your case: changing picture in a slideshow. The functions can be defined in another .js file with only the script, which you then have to load as an external file just like you hopefully did for the css (*the  part of your HTML is missing so hard to tell*). Or you can use a  tag inside of the index.html directly.

If you do have the corresponding JS, add it to your question and we can give further help.

Comment: I have added the javascript to the code